# Cannot access javascript methods this from inner function

Tags: javascript, this

Im having trouble reaching my object from a nested function. Ill just go right ahead and show the code.

```
function ChartObject(parent){
    this.CANVAS = document.createElement('canvas');
    parent.appendChild(this.CANVAS);

this.CANVAS.addEventListener('mousemove', function(evt){
var ctx = this.CANVAS.getContext("2d");//cannot access the CANVAS like this
//do stuff
}, false);

}
```

Ok so my problem is i cannot access the canvas object from the line:
    var ctx = this.CANVAS.getContext("2d");//cannot access the CANVAS like this

Comment: this.getContext("2d")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the event handler bound to `this.CANVAS` the canvas would be only `this`, as it is the bound element

```
function ChartObject(parent){
    this.CANVAS = document.createElement('canvas');
    parent.appendChild(this.CANVAS);

    this.CANVAS.addEventListener('mousemove', function(evt){
        var ctx = this.getContext("2d");
    }, false);

}
```

Comment: Wow thanks for the fast reply. Great job explaining it i understand this alot better now. I will accept as correct once 7 minuites has elapsed. Appreciate it

Comment: But say i need to get hold of the ChartObject becuase it has other variables other than this.CANVAS which is easy to get hold of?

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean? You can return anything from the function, or make a reference to the function and access it's properties?

Comment: Ok so imagine in my chart object uner this.CANVAS = document.createElement i have another variable like this.JSON. from the function(evt){} code i cannot access this.JSON

Comment: So baically i must create a SELF = this variable right in the ChartObject and from the nested addEventListener function call SELF.JSON instead of this.JSON.. Wow.. Javascript seems so weird compared to other languages. Terrible design no?

Comment: Yes, the easiest would be to use a variable to reference the outer this-value, like `self`, or jus a variable to hold the JSON, whatever fits -> https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/90gu23rk/

Comment: Ok brilliant. Thanks for the jsfiddle thats a nice touch. You really helped me out, thanks bud. 2 billion upvotes to you sir